# Paper trail for non-rails apps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sinatra, paper-trail-gem

I wonder if there's a library like `paper_trail` for `non-rails` applications (I use Sinatra).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind depending on ActiveRecord within your Sinatra app, you'll see that [PaperTrail now supports Sinatra](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail/blob/master/lib/paper_trail/frameworks/sinatra.rb).

Comment: Actually it only adds ActiveSupport, not ActiveRecord.

Comment: @kgilpin What's with this line then? https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail/blob/master/paper_trail.gemspec#L22 Or how about this statement in the README? "In order to configure PaperTrail for usage with Sinatra, your Sinatra app must be using ActiveRecord 3 or 4." Maybe something has changed since that was written?